# Why below apache Beam code return different output?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am learning apache beam using the Python SDK.
I came through some code on the beam website, and I have come up with some doubts.
Below is code from apache website.

```py
import apache_beam as beam
import re

class SplitWords(beam.DoFn):
  def __init__(self, delimiter=','):
    self.delimiter = delimiter

  def process(self, text):
    for word in text.split(self.delimiter):
      yield  word

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  plants = (
      pipeline
      | 'Gardening plants' >> beam.Create([
          'Strawberry,Carrot,Eggplant',
          'Tomato,Potato',
      ])
      | 'Split words' >> beam.ParDo(SplitWords(','))
      | beam.Map(print))
```

This is producing the following output.

Strawberry

Carrot

Eggplant

Tomato

Potato

From the documentation of Beam about the `return` statement of `ParDo`:
*You can also use a `return` statement with an `Iterable`, like a list or a generator*

But when I changed the code to use `return` instead of `yield`, it produced the following output.

```
import apache_beam as beam
import re

class SplitWords(beam.DoFn):
 def __init__(self, delimiter=','):
   self.delimiter = delimiter

 def process(self, text):
   for word in text.split(self.delimiter):
     *return  [word]*

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
 plants = (
     pipeline
     | 'Gardening plants' >> beam.Create([
         'Strawberry,Carrot,Eggplant',
         'Tomato,Potato',
     ])
     | 'Split words' >> beam.ParDo(SplitWords(','))
     | beam.Map(print))
```

Output:

Strawberry

Tomato

Why its like that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `return` instead of `yield`, but in this example the goal is to return a list. It's like a `flatMap` operation.

for the `yield`, you can repeat it for each element to return.

If you want to use return instead, you have to use and build a list and return it, example :

```py
def test_pipeline(self):
    with TestPipeline() as p:
        class SplitWords(beam.DoFn):
            def __init__(self, delimiter=','):
                self.delimiter = delimiter

            def process(self, text):
                plants = []
                for word in text.split(self.delimiter):
                    plants.append(word)

                return plants
            
        plants = (
                p
                | 'Gardening plants' >> beam.Create([
            'Strawberry,Carrot,Eggplant',
            'Tomato,Potato',
        ])
                | 'Split words' >> beam.ParDo(SplitWords(','))
                | beam.Map(print))
```

We have the expected result :

```
Strawberry
Carrot
Eggplant
Tomato
Potato
```

Comment: Going back to why there is a difference, the `return` statement in Python terminates the function execution (the loop is not resumed after the first element is returned). You can only return once. On the other hand the `yield` statement creates a generator where the code is continued (albeit in a deferred manner) after the yield statement (until a return or the end of the function is reached).

Comment: @robertwb, thanks for these details and explanations :)

Answer (score 0):

BTW: never mix return and yield. Check https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/22969 we are working on.

Comment: I would upvote this, because it is a good point, but it doesn't address the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Mazlum's answer is great and very detailed, but just to make clear the *specific* mistake that the OP made and the *simplest* way to convert it to something that would work:

### The original *incorrect* OP's code was:

```py
import apache_beam as beam
import re

class SplitWords(beam.DoFn):
 def __init__(self, delimiter=','):
   self.delimiter = delimiter

 def process(self, text):
   for word in text.split(self.delimiter):
     return  [word]

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
 plants = (
     pipeline
     | 'Gardening plants' >> beam.Create([
         'Strawberry,Carrot,Eggplant',
         'Tomato,Potato',
     ])
     | 'Split words' >> beam.ParDo(SplitWords(','))
     | beam.Map(print))
```

As mentioned, to use `return`, you need to return an `Iterable` (eg, a `list`).  To convert the above to a `return` which works properly, yet still looks as similar as possible, it would be:

### Fixed code as similar as possible

```py
import apache_beam as beam
import re

class SplitWords(beam.DoFn):
 def __init__(self, delimiter=','):
   self.delimiter = delimiter

 def process(self, text):
   return text.split(self.delimiter) ## <== This is the only altered code

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
 plants = (
     pipeline
     | 'Gardening plants' >> beam.Create([
         'Strawberry,Carrot,Eggplant',
         'Tomato,Potato',
     ])
     | 'Split words' >> beam.ParDo(SplitWords(','))
     | beam.Map(print))
```

### The mistake and the result seen

Apache beam will [break up `PCollections` in arbitrary groups](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/model/) to allow for parallelization.

The OP's incorrect code was splitting up the *object it received* into two `Iterable` objects, trying to iterate through each, *then returning early, after only the first value in each object is seen*, and returning that first value as a list.

The reason they got the strange

Strawberry

Tomato

output is because Apache Beam presumably broke the input up two objects to allow for the parallelization:

'Strawberry,Carrot,Eggplant'

and

'Tomato,Potato'

Since only the first element in each `Iterable` is being returned, the result ended up being

Strawberry

Tomato